# Page in page with telerik elements

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have two pages (MasterPage.aspx and ChildPage.aspx) with rad elements.
On the MasterPage.aspx I call the ChildPage.aspx through ajax (jQuery) and place the response (the entire ChildPage.aspx page) inside the MasterPage.aspx. My problem is that the MasterPage.aspx elements work but those (elements) that were generated on the ChildPage and placed in the MasterPage don't.
Which would be the best practice to load a page into another one with ajax, both pages containing rad elements that need RadScriptManager and RadAjaxManager?

MasterPage code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TelerikTest._Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'TestPage.aspx',
                type: "POST",
                data: "{ }",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#content").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<div>
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" Runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem1" 
            Value="RadComboBoxItem1" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem2" 
            Value="RadComboBoxItem2" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem3" 
            Value="RadComboBoxItem3" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadComboBox1">
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
</asp:Content>
```

ChildPage code:

> ```
> <form id="form2" runat="server">
> <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager2" runat="server">
> </telerik:RadScriptManager>
> <div>
>
>     <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" Runat="server">
>         <Items>
>             <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem1" 
>                 Value="RadComboBoxItem1" />
>             <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem2" 
>                 Value="RadComboBoxItem2" />
>             <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem3" 
>                 Value="RadComboBoxItem3" />
>         </Items>
>     </telerik:RadComboBox>
>
> </div>
> <telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server">
>     <AjaxSettings>
>         <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadComboBox2">
>         </telerik:AjaxSetting>
>     </AjaxSettings>
> </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
> </form>
> ```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web Forms support masterpages out the box - so you can specify a master page as e.g. MasterPage.master and populate child content within asp:ContentPlaceHolder blocks. This works with Telerik RadScriptManager proxy controls etc as necessary. Much info on the web e.g http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/creating-a-site-wide-layout-using-master-pages-cs

This may not explain your specific problem but without seeing the project or why you have setup this way I cannot comment.

Comment: I've added the code behind the two pages in my question. Thanks!

Comment: very nice. i'm sure there must be a reason you're loading content that way. still, could you not conditionally load user controls? Anyhow, I think you could start with removing the form tags from the child form. asp.net web forms does not support multiple form tags and you'll have a set of <form></form> in your master page?

Comment: Actually the content is loaded in this way on an event(not on document ready) but this is just an example to help you understand what I'm trying to do and reduce the code size. If I remove the <form></form> from the ChildPage, I get `Control 'ctl00SU' of type 'UpdatePanel' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server`